# 誰でも, 誰も, 何でも, 何も

Tags: grammar, word-choice, て-form, particle-も, polarity-items

> 何でも食べる

> 何も食べない

"it is as much as something, eat." = if it's anything, I'll eat it/I eat it.

"as much as something, not eat." = if it's anything, I will not/don't eat it.

何でもない = "it is as much as something, not" =  it is not even something

何もない = "as much as something, not" = even something is not

Why does the te form of desu do this? Am I also wrong with these translations? I am also aware of 何もが, which I think makes it apparent that nanimo is a noun from the use of ga to mark the subject. Am I confused here too?

Comment: This で is not the て form of です...

Comment: How is it not? Please clarify a bit.

Comment: The でも in 何でも食べる is definitely different from だ / です. I'm not sure if the でも in 何でもない is the same one or not.

Comment: How is it different? If that's the particle で it would be "as much as with something, eat" (even with something, i eat it) but it means "as much as something, eat" (if it's something, i eat it).
A little confused on how this links together still.

Comment: Are you aware that there are different で particles? Some of them come from にて and have nothing to do with the copula, even though they look identical to the て form of the copula.

Comment: Didn't know で came from にて, interesting. And I was only aware of one で particle, the other で being the て form of the copula.

Comment: Personally, I like to think of the で in 何でも and 誰でも as the "て-form of the copula" as well. It feels akin to constructions such as "どこに行っても..." (wherever I, you etc. go, ...). Thus, "何でも食べる" could be seen as "whatever it is, I will eat it". Like a shorter form of "何であっても食べる". Same with 誰でも: "Whoever it is, ...". "何でもない" in particular though is in my opinion just 何も + じゃない where the じゃない must again be unravelled into で(は)ない so that it can be combined with も properly. (What I wrote should, of course, not be taken as stone hard facts. Just my own way of looking at things.)